# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is not triggering in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and i am trying to create a WPF form and trying to call from another application . I am converting the WPF output as class libarary and calling from another Solution .

There is a .cs file which call this wpf window from code behind using below code .

```
    Thread thre = new thread(()=> 
    {
      mainwindow md = new mainwindow();
      md.ShowDialog();
      md.Closed+=(s,e)=> md.dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
      Dispatcher.Run()
    });
    thre.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thre.Start();
```

I Can able to call my window and all my functionality working excel the dispachter.beginInvoke is not triggering .And i also get Application.Current =null .  I am unable to go to if statement in the below code.

Method in window.cs

```
new Thread(()=>
    {
      rsult= getItemID("44");
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new ThreadStart(()=>{
        if(rsult==0)
          {}
      });
    }).Start();
  }
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, there is a closing bracket too much in the file window.cs

Comment: `md.ShowDialog();` will block the code until the window is closed afaik, so the following statements wont be called initially

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` blocks. You should register your event handler, show the window by calling the `Show()` method and then start the message pump by calling `Run()`:

```
Thread thre = new thread(()=> 
{
  mainwindow md = new mainwindow();
  md.Closed += (s,e) => md.dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
  md.Show();
  Dispatcher.Run()
});
thre.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thre.Start();
```